# How to make json data in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, json

I have an array which looks something like below:

```
[
        {
            name: "ReceiverId",
            value: "1"
        },
        {name: "TransSequence", value: "KPJ7dL2pmx0njInNRAzUug"},
        {
            name: "email-address",
            value: "xcv@cvb.com"
        },
        {
            name: "mobile-number",
            value: "9321313213"
        },
        {
            name: "ReceiverId",
            value: "2"
        },
        {
            name: "TransSequence",
            value: "KPJ7dL2pmx0njInNRAzUug"
        },
        {
            name: "email-address",
            value: "xcv@cvb.com"
        }


    ]
```

Now I want to make my json data looks like this:

```
{
    "MainData": [
      {
      "TransSequence": "wpiuVJw",
        "ReceiverId": "1",    
        "ReceiverEmail": "xcv@cvb.com",
        "ReceiverMobileNo": "9321313213",
      },
      {  
        "TransSequence": "xowpiuVJw",
        "ReceiverId": "2",    
        "ReceiverEmail": "xcv@cvb.com",
        "ReceiverMobileNo": "9321313213",
      }
    ]
    }
```

However I tried below code snippet:

```
mArr = []
obj = {};
for(var i=0; i<mainArr.length; i++){

//  obj = {};
    for(j = 0; j < 4; j++){
        obj[mainArr[i].name] = mainArr[i].value
    }
}
```

But above code snippet returns the last values only. However, I have also tried to convert into string based json but in last array it return as `,` which throws error while parsing it.

**HELP WOULD BE APPRECIATED!!**

Comment: How are you getting the data? Why is it in that format and not in the desired one?

Comment: And how is all of that related to the illuminati? Err.. I mean... `java`?

Comment: Whoa talk about picking a language to work with, this guy is working with python, java, javascript, and php

Comment: What is the logic of converting the first one to the second one?

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and post a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  You're close to an MVCE here, but please actually put it together (assign the array in the code and post a complete *minimal* program.)  Please remove the misleading tags -- is it javascript, python, java, or PHP?  It's certainly not all four.  Add a `json` tag to get the best chance for the right person to look at your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basing the code you tried, you are using js.

In js, you can use `reduce` to summarize the array. Use `Object.assign` to combine objects.

```js
let arr = [{"name":"ReceiverId","value":"1"},{"name":"TransSequence","value":"KPJ7dL2pmx0njInNRAzUug"},{"name":"email-address","value":"xcv@cvb.com"},{"name":"mobile-number","value":"9321313213"},{"name":"ReceiverId","value":"2"},{"name":"TransSequence","value":"KPJ7dL2pmx0njInNRAzUug"},{"name":"email-address","value":"xcv@cvb.com"},{"name":"mobile-number","value":"9321231321"},{"name":"ReceiverId","value":"1"},{"name":"TransSequence","value":"KPJ7dL2pmx0njInNRAzUug"},{"name":"email-address","value":"xcv@cvb.com"},{"name":"mobile-number","value":"9321231321"},{"name":"ReceiverId","value":"2"}];


let propertyCount = 4;
let result = arr.reduce((c, v, i) => {
  let o = Math.floor(i / propertyCount);
  c[o] = c[o] || {};
  c[o] = Object.assign(c[o], {[v.name]: v.value});
  return c;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct code

```js
let mainArr = [{"name":"ReceiverId","value":"1"},{"name":"TransSequence","value":"KPJ7dL2pmx0njInNRAzUug"},{"name":"email-address","value":"xcv@cvb.com"},{"name":"mobile-number","value":"9321313213"},{"name":"ReceiverId","value":"2"},{"name":"TransSequence","value":"KPJ7dL2pmx0njInNRAzUug"},{"name":"email-address","value":"xcv@cvb.com"},{"name":"mobile-number","value":"9321231321"},{"name":"ReceiverId","value":"1"},{"name":"TransSequence","value":"KPJ7dL2pmx0njInNRAzUug"},{"name":"email-address","value":"xcv@cvb.com"},{"name":"mobile-number","value":"9321231321"}];

const obj = {
    MainData: [],
}
for(var i=0; i<mainArr.length / 4; i++){

    const local = {}
    for(j = i * 4; j < i * 4 + 4; j++){
        local[mainArr[j].name] = mainArr[j].value
    }
    obj.MainData.push(local);
}

console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my take:

```js
const input = [
    {name: "ReceiverId", value: "1"},
    {name: "TransSequence", value: "KPJ7dL2pmx0njInNRAzUug"},
    {name: "email-address", value: "xcv@cvb.com"},
    {name: "mobile-number", value: "9321313213"},
    {name: "ReceiverId", value: "2"},
    {name: "TransSequence", value: "KPJ7dL2pmx0njInNRAzUug"},
    {name: "email-address", value: "xcv@cvb.com"},
    {name: "mobile-number", value: "9321231321"},
    {name: "ReceiverId", value: "1"},
    {name: "TransSequence", value: "KPJ7dL2pmx0njInNRAzUug"},
    {name: "email-address", value: "xcv@cvb.com"},
    {name: "mobile-number", value: "9321231321"},
    {name: "ReceiverId", value: "2"}
];

let data = [];
input.forEach(e => {
    // If it's a new data point, add it.
    if (e.name === 'ReceiverId') {
        data.push({
            ReceiverId: e.value
        })
    // Add it to the last array.
    } else {
        data[data.length-1][e.name] = e.value
    }
})

let output = {
    MainData: data
}

// Your output
console.log(output)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {min-height: 100%;}
```